# Simply populate database table names in Android ListView

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

Very new to Android development...I've been scouring the internet for answers, but I'm still finding myself stuck and hoping someone can lend me a hand.  I absolutely admit I am a newbie...but trying to learn.

I have an already populated sqlite database that I am including in a package.  I've copied this into the asset folder.  The database has 4 tables (and some fields beneath that).

I have a simple activity with a listview that I am trying to simply query the database for the table names and have them populate, however I get no results.

my DataBaseAdapter code is essentially the code from here:
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

I modified my database name and path.

My class code to call this is here:

ON EDIT:::

```
public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

    return myDbHelper.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'",
            new String[]{});
}

private void fillData() {

    Cursor c = fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] {"name"};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.listview};


    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.list_view, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);

            }

    }
```

The project runs, it just yields no results in the ListView (which is in an xml named lists.xml)  the portion of code is here:

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />    

         <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#000000"
           android:text="No data"
           style="@style/ButtonText"/>
```

Any help would be great, I'm sure I am flailing hard on my sql calls...but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Your to and from arrays are incorrect.  Your 'from' string array is currently blank.  This is going to be the name of the column you are trying to display.  So in your case it will be "name".  Your 'to' array is going to be the id of the view you are mapping the value to...not the id of the list.  You will need to create a new layout with a TextField in it to display.  In the 'to' field you will then give the id of this new text field.  Then in the SimpleCursorAdapter you can send in this new layout along with the 'to' and 'from' arrays.

Comment: Nick, I really appreciate the response to this.  I created a new layout file named "list_view" and within in a TextView with an ID of listview. I edited my code snipits above to show my changes.  I still see nothing populated within the activity when I launch it.  Just to confirm, the database does exist within the application data when I view it through DDMS.  Can you think of anything else I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
private void getData() {

            tb.open();

            List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

             Cursor c = tb.fetchallemployee();
             c.moveToFirst(); 

             ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                             R.layout.show_database, c,
                             new String[] {"date", "title"},
                             new int[] {R.id.toptext, R.id.bottomtext});
             setListAdapter(adapter);

             setListAdapter(entries);

             tb.close(); 
        }
```